# Regarding Button Clicking in android

Tags: android

I have an application in Android 2.3.3. There are few buttons in it. I want a functionality (for the buttons) similar to that of qwerty keyboard, where in when we press a key or a letter, that character will be shown for a fraction of a second, just above the place where that character is present in the keyboard.

Do we have any such kind of properties built in?

If there is no such thing, i am using a background color to my buttons and it's hard to get a note of whether the button is clicked or not. Can we somehow make it visible that the button is clicked.

Comment: I guess selector can help you in doing so... giving feedback to the user that button is clicked.. See http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for a selector
somehting like this inside your drawable folder. 
To reference it just call it like a drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonnotpressed" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: using different images will get my thing done.. But i thought there would a simple solution to this. After all, it's just button click and a very basic animation...

Comment: Yes that is all that happens when you see a button clicked most of the time a different image is displayed for a split second.  Even when you click a keyboard button there is an image that shows up above the button that displays what letter it was. Every time it is a separate image. What do you think an animation is? Its a series of different images displayed to you in succession to trick your eye into thinking that it was fluid.

Comment: I think i will just change the background of the button on click. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems to me like you should try and create an XML file that describes the button different states instead of what you're currently doing.

if you still want to show the buttons layout as a popup when the button ius pressed, you should create a view and add it when intercepting the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and remove it when intercepting  the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Comment: so no built in method or something that is around, to get this done in a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below `xml` for UI `button` selection :

`buttonselection.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_focused="false" 
  android:state_selected="false" 
  android:state_pressed="false" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/image you want to display on page load"/> 
<item android:state_focused="false" 
  android:state_selected="true" 
  android:state_pressed="false" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/image you want to display on selection"/> 
<item android:state_focused="true" 
  android:state_selected="false" 
  android:state_pressed="false" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/image you want to display on page load"/> 
<item android:state_focused="true" 
  android:state_selected="true" 
  android:state_pressed="false" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/image you want to display on selection"/> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/image you want to display on selection"/> 
</selector>
```

and below is the code for binding with `xml`:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
   ImageButton btYourLayoutBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
  btYourLayoutBtn .setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonselection);
  btYourLayoutBtn .setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

Comment: This is the same idea that i gave you but it has all of the different states of a button. Maybe Missing one? I believe there are 6 but i may be wrong. For each state you can display a different image. All of these states are not always needed or used. For example you must have a direction pad or keyboard to select a button without pressing it. You cannot select a button by just touching it.